# how to insert a "NULL" in Number field from c#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

i am inserting a value from datarow to access database and if the row[1] value is blank it throws an error Data type mismatch in criteria expression and if value is there it insert properly. what i am missing here. in access the column1 is of type Number.

```
string SNumber = row[1].ToString();

if (SNumber.ToString() != null)
{
    if (SNumber .ToString() != "")
    {
        SNumber = row[1].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        SNumber = "NULL";
        SNumber = DBNull.Value.ToString();
    }
}

insert into table1 (Column1) values (SNumber);
```

Comment: There is not a lot of clarity on the data types here. What is the data type of the field in the database? What is the data type of the column at index `1`?

Comment: @ neoistheone : the datatype of the field is "Number" in access database.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, if row[1] is null then you will receive an exception too. if row[1] can return a nullable datatype (which is not clear in your question) then maybe you should replace:

```
 string SNumber = row[1].ToString();
```

with

```
 Number SNumber = row[1];
```

and then replace your outer if-statement with:

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SNumber.ToString())) {
    [..]
    }
```

Comment: this line `string SNumber = row[1];` wouldn't compile as it's not a string

Comment: True! Updated! I don´t realize what datatype is returned from row[1], since it is not clear from the OP Q.

Comment: @Marcus: the datatype of the field is "Number" in access database.

Comment: In that case, if Number is the datatype, you should be able to apply what I used in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There may be possibility that the row value is blank or may be null. So only checking null is not sufficient, you have to check for both null then an empty sting as blank is not allowed for Number datatypes.

May be you can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`

try this

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[1].ToString())
{
   // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all of your code with a ternary operator:

```
string query = "insert into table1 (Column1) values (" + 
        ((row[1] != null && row[1].ToString() != String.Empty) 
            ? row[1].ToString() 
            : null)
    + ") etc... etc...";
```

if I understand what you want correctly.  If row[1] is null or empty, insert null.  Else insert row[1]'s value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I suppose `Column1` is a numeric field. And then if you try to insert string it will throws an error, because

```
SNumber = "NULL";
```

is a **String**. If it was:

```
SNumber = NULL;
```

then this will be a null value. But maybe it will be better to use Nullable int - Nullable types <sup>[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)</sup>

```
int? num = null;
```

The question mark point that it can hold also a `NULL` value. Hope this helps.